# "Classical" Coherence

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, laser, coherence

I'm having a couple of courses where the concept of [coherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_%28physics%29) is quite important. I know the traditional definition of coherence and it's connection to the phase of a wave. But often, I found, that our teachers did not explain it really well. So, I started reading a little bit on coherence and I realized that several sources seem to be contradicting or did not go along with what our teachers told us.
Then I found an article (http://amasci.com/miscon/coherenc.html) which says that, more or less, most standard textbook explain the concept wrong.

Therefore I'm hoping that someone can give me a good formal definition or a source which is explaining the phenomenon nicely. Because right now, I'm awfully confused and the only thing I know is that a monochromatic, point-source is coherent.

Comment: Are you asking for a definition of the word "coherence"?

Comment: The 'article'  (a blogpost on the author's personal page) is quite awful. The author appears to have had an earlier misconception of light following a sinusoidal path, when the sine waves just describe the E and M fields. The author mixes up spatial transverse coherence (see VanCittert-Zernike Theorem) and temporal (spatially longitudinal) coherence. Worse the author mixes up rays (geometrical optics) with other concepts.  Coherence is best understood in the electro-magnetic approximation first. There are plenty of good textbooks, none of which will be as bad as this blogpost.

Comment: That is why I said that I'm confused. I see that he mixes up a lot, but he also brings up some points which, I think, our Teachers did wrong as well. If you could tell me the textbooks I will gladly read up on that.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, even the wikipedia article goes at this exactly the wrong way. Coherence is simply a matter of non-zero autocorrelation of waves. Neither perfect coherence nor perfect incoherence are physically possible, the physical region between the two corner cases requires that you study the Fourier transform and auto-correlation functions of the waves. In practice a fairly high level of both spatial and temporal coherence are easily achievable even when starting from strongly incoherent sources.

Comment: Personally I never understood coherence until I looked at it in terms of (1) Liouville's theorem and conservation of brightness, and (2) quantum mechanical density operators. The concepts of "coherence" and "pure state" aren't quite the same, but they're somewhat related. That said...sorry, no, I've never seen a good reference on this and I fully agree that there's a lot of misinformation on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is this: When fields are added (superimposed), their phase can either average out evenly, or remain fixed. The former case describes incoherent fields, the later coherent ones. These are the extremes; anything in between is possible. Situations where the degree of coherence needs to be quantified hence depend on how long or how far you average.